# it is possible to use features maps of CNN to localised important areas in image?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm new in deep learning and CNN, I understand how convolutional and pooling layers work, I understand how and why feature maps are created.  How I can localize from the feature maps important area in the original image? is that possible? 
I.e. I use my own  data  ( medical image ) 
Feeding those images to my neural network I can receive maps features and calculate from them the probability of each class. 
But how from that feature maps I can get know where exactly those areas are? 
I will use those areas for another application?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You have to check the weights in the network and back track them from your output, and then you can color the original pixels that lead to the decision. IBM provides this natively in their platform, I'm sure others do as well.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thank you for your comment, can you be more specific
haw can I back from the weights? you mentioned IBM, do you have a link?

Comment: Probably on their cloud Watson platform, but only saw it used. What I would do is get the output of each layer, then from the output figure out which inputs of this layer added a positive weight, and then move to the connected nodes to the previous layer and do the same. You should end up in your image with a set of interesting kernels.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher  thanks a lot, I hope it will help me :))